# VoiceOver is reading two different spans as if they were one span

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers

I have the following structure in my markup:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <span>a</span>
        <span>b</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>c</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

"a" and "c" always contain text.

"b" sometimes contains text, sometimes is empty.

When "b" contains text, navigating through the elements with VoiceOver works as expected: each span is announced separately.

When "b" is empty, VoiceOver announces "a" and "c" together, as if they were once sentence.

I would like the spans containing "a" and "c" to be announced separately when "b" is empty.

I have tried using ChromeVox and cannot replicate the issue with it, so this appears to be unique to VoiceOver.

Thank you

Comment: `<div>` and  `<span>` are semantically nurtured. Try `<p>` instead of `<div>` because  structured sentences are expected within a `<p>`aragraph. `<span>`a`</span><span>b</span>` is rendered as "ab", so `<p>`ab`</p>` should be interpreted as a single sentence as should `<p>`c`</p>` .

Comment: Voiceover on Mac or on iPhone? And when you navigate, are you swiping right or using some other gesture?

Comment: @zer00ne - this seems to still result in the same effect. in the context of the original markup changing the <div> for a <p> also messes with the layout a bit.

Comment: @slugolicious this is on Mac - I'm navigating using VO+arrows

Comment: @StaśWerno Yeah, I'd actually test it out and have a definitive answer but I don't have my Mac ATM. ‍♂️